# Determine profileID or pageID from iframe using PHP / Facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to determine the ID of the user profile or fan page that a user has installed my app into as a tab.

I have a generic script that runs and can be customized depending on the user or page ID. If the script doesn't pick up any of ID's, then a generic 'out of service' is returned.

Answer (score 0):

After including the [FB PHP SDK](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/), this is the script I got:

```
<?php    
require_once 'facebook.php'; // include Facebook PHP SDK
    $me = $facebook->api('/me'); //Get user object
    $userid = $me['id']; Get User ID
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible because we can only get `page_id` from a signed request.

I'm also stuck with the same problem. What I need is to get `page_id` at the time of my app installation and I'm using this `page_id` for tracking the users when they are accessing my app through their facebook page. I'm giving access to my app only to certain registered members so finally I decided to generate an authcode when my clients configuring the facebook app from my website and prompt them to enter the authcode when they are accessing my app first time if they have done that successfully we can easly store the `page_id` to our database from the signed request. I think this is the only solution for this.
I'm happy if anyone else can find a solution for this.

What we need is a `page_id` of a user facebook page when they are installing our facebook app.